# Switching from Unity to KDE deleted all my Chrome cookies

Tags: 16.04, unity, google-chrome, kde

When I switched from Unity to KDE and launched Chrome, at first the Chrome Sync feature was "disconnected" - Chrome was telling me that my Google login credentials have changed and it can't sync to my Google account (though the title bar still displayed the Google account I was using in Chrome under Unity). I entered my login data into chrome successfully, which made Chrome Sync work. But all my cookies were gone - I was logged out of all sites.

What might have been the cause of this, and can I get my cookies back?

Comment: The Chrome profile shouldn't be affected by a different DE. I suppose something else happened... Regarding the cookies, that's easy: Login again to those sites and you'll have the cookies back in no time.

Comment: I have to add, that this happened on my fathers computer also.  Simply installing kubuntu-desktop, rebooting, and switching to it, caused Chrome to loose the saved passwords and cookies.

Sadly I don't know if there is a way to get it back, we simply just re-signed in to everything.