# Google chrome looses all cookies when logging in a different desktop environment (ubuntu and i3)

Tags: google-chrome, i3-wm

See the title, I am using the same application in both cases and same account, but I have to login again everytime, which is not expected behavior. If I leave i3, go on Ubuntu desktop and back on i3, I lost all the cookies saved in i3.

Ubuntu version:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Google chrome version `Google Chrome 95.0.4638.69`.

i3 version: `i3 version 4.18.2 (2020-07-26) © 2009 Michael Stapelberg and contributors`

Possible duplicate of [this unresolved post from 2017](https://askubuntu.com/questions/870731/switching-from-unity-to-kde-deleted-all-my-chrome-cookies) and [this unresolved post from beg 2021](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1304746/i3-wm-google-chrome-passwords-not-saved).

Comment: There are different cookies depending on the google account; if you switch accounts, it will only show the cookies for tat account.

Comment: I don't switch accounts, I just change the desktop environment at the login page using the geared wheel. It is still the same user (and consequently same password). My synchronized chrome settings are still there in both cases.

Comment: the link below describes 2 commands that need to be added to the i3 config files to be able to work correctly even after logging out of each wm...
But first you need to setup the PAM as described in section 3.1 https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GNOME/Keyring#Launching_gnome-keyring-daemon_outside_desktop_environments_(KDE,_GNOME,_XFCE,_...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem switching from KDE to Cinnamon and was surprised to find few answers on the internet. The issue appears to be related to desktop environments relying on different password stores. In my case, I could load a logged-in chrome within Cinnamon by running:

```
google-chrome --password-store=kwallet5
```

since my logins were made from within KDE. (This makes very little sense and may be a bug since kwallet manager shows zero stored Chrome Keys, and chrome appears to be using its internal password store, not my DE's.)

In the case of i3, I came across this helpful [comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/i3wm/comments/81i9tl/gnome_keyring_not_working_well_with_i3/dv5lybs/).

> Trying adding `exec --no-startup-id /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=secrets` to your i3 config. Chrome should be started with `--password-store=gnome`, otherwise it auto-detects which password storage to use depending on the DE. In i3 it defaults to plain text.

It appears that chrome is not trying to be smart enough. It does not make an attempt to look for different keyrings that might be in use, but simply makes a guess based on the DE it finds itself in.

Comment: Thanks, using `--password-store=basic` fixed my issue with loosing login data when switching between Enlightenment / KDE Plasma.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 and I can report that the solution with --password-store=gnome does not work anymore at least for me.
I'm using --password-store=gnome-libsecret.

If you want to continue to use the i3 dmenu you can add into folder inside your $PATH (e.g. $HOME/.local/bin/) a custom script named `chrome` like this one:

```
#!/bin/bash
google-chrome --password-store=gnome-libsecret
```

If you don't see the new entry `chrome` it in dmenu try to delete the cache in `$HOME/.cache/dmenu_run`.